# angular js gridOptions

Tags: angularjs

I have a question.

In this code

```
{{gridOptions4[0].no}}
```

output is `1`.

but in this code:

```
var i=0;
{{gridOptions4[i].no}}
```

output is no data.

Why is this value coming out?

Comment: That is because you have probably not made `i` as a class variable. You use `angular` or `angularjs`?

Comment: angular js .......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value in your html file use  `$scope.i=0;`, if you use `var i = 0;`, it means its local variable, in view it will not able to use the value of `i`. The following change will work for you:

```
$scope.i=0;
{{gridOptions4[i].no}}
```

Comment: <div class="gallery">
 <% for (var i=0; i < {{gridOptions4[i].name}}; i++) { %>
    <div class="{{gridOptions4[0].class}}">

      <div class="gallery-item">

        <a href="{{gridOptions4[0].main_href}}">

          <div class="gallery-item-image"> <img ng-src="{{gridOptions4[0].imgsrc}}"></div>

        </a>

        <div class="gallery-item-description">

          <p align="center">{{gridOptions4[0].name}}</p>

   
           
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <% } %>
  </div>

Comment: but Unexpected token { in D:\OneDrive\디자인과제\1.개발 코드\1.Design_Web\views\concept.ejs while compiling ejs If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint: https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint

Comment: full code is  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="BasicCtrl20"> 
<div class="posts">
  <div class="gallery">
 <% for (var i=0; i < {{gridOptions4[i].name}}; i++) { %>
    <div class="{{gridOptions4[i].class}}">

      <div class="gallery-item">
        <a href="{{gridOptions4[i].main_href}}">
          <div class="gallery-item-image"> <img ng-src="{{gridOptions4[i].imgsrc}}"></div>
        </a>

        <div class="gallery-item-description">
          <p align="center">{{gridOptions4[0].name}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <% } %>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="BasicCtrl20"> 
<div class="posts"> <div class="gallery"> 
<div ng-repeat = "gridoptions in gridOptions4"> 
        <div class="{{gridOptions.class}}"> 
        <div class="gallery-item"> 
        <a href="{{gridOptions.main_href}}"> 
        <div class="gallery-item-image"> 
        <img ng-src="{{gridOptions.imgsrc}}">
        </div> </a> <div class="gallery-item-description"> 
<p align="center">{{gridOptions.name}}</p> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div>

Comment: i want image add comment how to add image in comment??

Comment: Repeat is good but Database data does not come in. How should I fix it?

Comment: my angular code var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('BasicCtrl20', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("/concept_db")
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.gridOptions4 = response.data;
     
  });

});

Comment: <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="BasicCtrl20"> 
<div class="posts"> <div class="gallery"> 
<div ng-repeat = "gridoptions in gridOptions4"> 
        <div class="{{gridOptions.class}}"> 
        <div class="gallery-item"> 
        <a href="{{gridOptions.main_href}}"> 
        <div class="gallery-item-image"> 
        <img ng-src="{{gridOptions.imgsrc}}">
        </div> </a> <div class="gallery-item-description"> 
<p align="center">{{gridOptions.name}}</p> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> 
</div>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50634553/how-to-fix-my-code-angularjs-ejs-code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50634553/how-to-fix-my-code-angularjs-ejs-code
I put a link on it.
I wrote down the modified code and the results.