# how to fix my code?? angularjs, ejs code

Tags: angularjs, ejs

I used angular js and ejs.
Repeat is good but, Database data does not come in.

How should I fix my code?

In this angularjs code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('BasicCtrl20', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("/concept_db")
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.gridOptions4 = response.data;

  });

});
```

In this my code

```
<div class="container">
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="BasicCtrl20"> 
   <div class="row">
<span style="line-height:30px"><br></span>

<div class="toggles">
   <button id="showall">전체 제품 보기</button> 
  <button id="furniture">가구/인테리어</button>
  <button id="homeappliances">디지털 가전</button>
  <button id="life">생활/건강</button>
  <button id="sport">스포츠/레저</button>
  <button id="delivery">출산/육아</button>
  <button id="fashion">패션잡화</button>
</div>

<div class="posts">
    <div class="gallery">
        <div ng-repeat="gridoptions in gridOptions4">
            <div class="{{gridOptions.class}}">
                <div class="gallery-item">
                    <a href="{{gridOptions.main_href}}">
                        <div class="gallery-item-image">
                            <img ng-src="{{gridOptions.imgsrc}}">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="gallery-item-description">
                        <p align="center">{{gridOptions.name}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and reuslt
[image]

I want to import data from the database.

console log result
[image]

Comment: The `$http` functions can take error callbacks, you should include one and see what error it throws or check the response from the network tab to see what is going wrong.  Nothing appears to be wrong with the code that we can see.

Comment: var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('BasicCtrl20', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("/concept_db")
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.gridOptions4 = response.data;

  },
  function(error) {
    console.log(error)
  });
});

Comment: check for error

Comment: Nothing is displayed in the console log.
I attached the console log picture.

Comment: I Solved problem   "<div ng-repeat="gridoptions in gridOptions4">" ----------------> "<div ng-repeat="x in gridOptions4">"

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of elements, so there is clearly *something* there. `ng-repeat` does not create 20 elements from an error or thin air.

But the field name is probably wrong. It is not `name` (or `name` is actually empty on every item in the database!). Check that you got the field name right. Maybe its upper case `Name` or `NAME` or mispellt `naem`. Or something completely different like `label` or `title`.

the easy thing to do is to log the data when you get it, and see for yourself.

```
.then(function(response) {
    console.log( response.data );  <-- look in the console!
    scope.gridOptions4 = response.data;
```

Or since it's a GET-request. Right-click that link in your console `XHR finished loading: GET "https://localhost:3000/concept_db".` <-- Right-click, open in a new tab.  It might not be the most easy thing to read, but it's a such a quick thing to just take a peek at data so you know what you are working with.

Comment: [{"no":1,"class":"life post","main_href":"Library_Main3_1?pageKey=1","imgsrc":"images/Library_Main/bottle.jpg","name":"Bottle"}

Comment: Yup, looks good. Next step is to see if the data is in the html (obscured by css or something else, fonts maybe).  Right-click one of the gallery-cards and inspect. Or use ctrl+shift+C, click item.

Comment: I Solved problem   "<div ng-repeat="gridoptions in gridOptions4">" ----------------> "<div ng-repeat="x in gridOptions4">"

Comment: Aha,  `ng-repeat="gridoptions` --> `gridOptions`. Glad you found it. That should still not output 20 elements, but oh well.